# hive counting same field many times

Tags: hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I need to count how many students are from which college but when i am using below query

> select college ,COUNT(*) from students group by college ;

i am getting this result

[image]

result showing different counts for same colleges 
what should i do here so i can get the proper count of colleges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have many different names of the same college, like these

```
JIIT
"JIIT
jiit
```

Try to normalize them (convert to uppercase and remove `'"'`), so it will be the same `JIIT` after `group by`:

```
 select case when college = 'BSA' then 'BSA College of Technology'
        --add other cases
        else --rule for others
            trim(upper(regexp_replace(college,'"',''))) 
         end as college 
       ,COUNT(*)                                    as cnt 
   from students 
  group by 
        case when college = 'BSA' then 'BSA College of Technology'
        --add other cases
        else --rule for others
            trim(upper(regexp_replace(college,'"',''))) 
         end --the same sentence should be in group by, or use subquery instead
;
```

Apply `case` to convert more complex strings like `MJP ROHILKHAND` and `M J P ROHILKHAND` to the same.

And this happens because the database is not normalized and input is not restricted for `College` column by College dimension.

Comment: thank you for the help and can i do something about the college name which are in short form like in database i have some college name which are in short form and full form

Comment: @palashchoubey  Only like this: `case college when 'One form' then 'another form' when 'this' then 'that' ... else college end as college`, combine both solutions

Comment: @palashchoubey See updated answer with more complex rule. You see, you can use any technics using regex, case, etc to transform names and reduce their varieties before grouping them